# Windows FTP Client - Think Transmit for Mac

Tags: windows, ftp

Im on the hunt for a decent FTP client for windows. Im looking for something that works in a similar way to transmit for mac.

Features im looking for ideally would be the ability to synchronize files between local and server, and most interestingly, to mount an ftp server as a seperate drive.

I know i can get individual programs to do each if those, but im looking for an all in one solution... Any ideas?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [Mac's Transmit & Forklift ftp client / windows equivalent](http://superuser.com/questions/180009/macs-transmit-forklift-ftp-client-windows-equivalent)?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of, but does your FTP provider provide a shell extension for Windows to get it on as a drive?

I personally use [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) as my FTP client but that doesn't have those features you want. :/

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any software to add FTP servers as network drives in Windows.  In XP you can add them in My Network Places, and in Vista onwards you right click inside My Computer and select Add Network Location.

[Ipswitch WS_FTP Pro](http://www.ipswitchft.com/Products/Ws_Ftp_Pro/) is full featured and can sync and also has a feature called HotDrop, which may interest you.

[image: Ipswitch WS_FTP Pro]