# Mac's Transmit & Forklift ftp client / windows equivalent

Tags: windows, software-rec, ftp

Is there anybody who knows some really good ftp / dual pane / folder sync (local and ftp)?

Something like [panic's transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/) or [binarynights' forklift](http://www.binarynights.com/) ?

The best I used is filezilla, but it feels so old compared to mac's clients...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before switching to Mac (and Transmit, of course) I was an avid user of [FlashFXP](http://www.flashfxp.com), which should offer all the features you speak of.

Answer (score 1):

[WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/introduction) includes FTP support and is probably the closest I've seen to Transmit on the Mac for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[CuteFTP Pro](http://cuteftp.com/cuteftppro/) can do it, although it's not free

I personally like [SmartFTP](http://www.smartftp.com/). I don't remember paying for it after a month, so I guess that's some new "feature".. It doesn't state if it will stop working after one month or just flip to a simple ftp client, but I guess you could try it.